# Sunspot/Solr raketasks not loading in Rails 3 Mountable Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sunspot, rails-engines, sunspot-solr

I'm trying to add the [sunspot_rails](https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot) gem to my [Rails Mountable Engine](https://github.com/StefanHagen/badmin), so I can use Solr to do full text searches. Like it states in the README file I've added this to my Gemfile:

```
gem "sunspot_rails"
gem "sunspot_solr"
```

Then I run `rails g sunspot_rails:install` which creates `sunspot.yml` in the `config` folder of my Rails Engine. To start sunspot I need to run:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
```

But that doesn't work, and gives me the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'sunspot:solr:start'
```

It seems that it doesn't load the Sunspot/Solr rake tasks, and so it can't find them. I've had other issues with the Rails engine not loading files that would load automatically in a normal Rails 3 application. I suspect something along that line is going on here as well. I checked the `lib/tasks` folder, and there is only one file in there: `my_app.rake`. In that file there are only a few *commented* lines of code:

```
# desc "Explaining what the task does"
# task :my_app do
#   # Task goes here
# end
```

I think I would maybe need to add the raketasks manually, and load them from `my_app.rake`. However, I can't find any information on how to do this, and I maybe I'm completely wrong in the first place. Hopefully someone on stackoverflow has experience with this.

In any case, thank you very much for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few days ago found a solution to this problem myself, so for the sake of completeness and (hopefully) to be of help to others, I will post my solution here.

The problem actually occurs because a Rails 3 Mountable Engine behaves a lot LIKE a normal Rails app, but also has a lot of minor/major differences. You just have to run `bundle exec rake app:sunspot:solr:start` instead of just `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`.

So to get Sunspot working in a Rails 3 Mountable Engine, I followed these steps:

**Add to Gemfile**

```
# Gemfile (Don't forget to move them to your gemspec when packaging your engine)

gem 'sunspot_solr' #only for development mode
gen 'sunspot_rails'
```

After that, don't forget to run `bundle install` to install the gems.

**Configure your engine to use Sunspot/Solr**

To generate the needed `config/sunspot.yml` file run:

```
rails generate sunspot_rails:install
```

**Start Solr on your local machine**

Finally, to start a local instance of Solr run:

```
bundle exec rake app:sunspot:solr:start
```

*And now you are all set!*